# Non-Custodial Bitcoin IRAs

Tags: investing

Is there anyway to create an IRA with bitcoins that doesn't involve giving up my keys -- a non-custodial account?

I know, for example, that [Bitcoin IRA](https://bitcoinira.com/) will create a bitcoin-funded IRA, but I won't actually own the bitcoins since they will set up a custodial account.  I suspect the answer is a flat "no" since the IRS requires IRAs to have administrators.  But maybe administration != possessing the keys...

Comment: Off Topic. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: If you want the keys, why don't you simply hold bitcoin?  What's the point of the IRA?

Comment: IRAs are tax deferred accounts but require an administrator.